# POCO C++ library is not compiling with CMAke and MinGW. Thread_WIN32.cpp __except error

Tags: c++, cmake, poco, mingw-w64

everyone. I try to build POCO C++ library with CMake and MinGW compiler, but I receive syntax error in POCO Thread_WIN32.cpp file (Picrealted). I think it is somehow related with compiler exact version, posix-sjlj. Has anyone encountered this problem?

Setup:

- Windows 10
- MinGW-W64 x86_64-posix-sjlj-rev0 8.1.0
- CMake 3.26.0-rc1

[error pic (link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QB4y.png)

**UPDATE 1**

I tried another version of MinGW-w64 (MinGW-W64 x86_64-posix-**seh**-rev0 8.1.0), but it also didn't work. I have another question: maybe compiler just makes it's job right? In Thread_WIN32.cpp file from POCO GitHub in setThreadName function no __catch before __except. Why? Mustn't it be there?

[pic of setThreadName function from POCO GitHub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsHYg.png)

**UPDATE 2**
Okay, after __try shoudn't be __catch, after __try follows __except and that's all. This is microsoft own way to handle errors - SEH. But I wonder hard is there some way to properly use MinGW-w64 compiler with SEH. I read about __try1 and __except1 in MinGW, but Internet said that it might be unsafe and very painful

Comment: Looking at the error message I think it  has more to do with compiler specific code, specifically `__except` is a Microsoft specific keyword for structured exception handling. AFAIK MinGW does not support it. So either you need to use Microsoft's compiler, or there is some more configuration that you have to do to make the code compatible with the compiler you are using.

Comment: From the [POCO website](https://docs.pocoproject.org/current/99150-WindowsPlatformNotes.html) this quote *'Basic support for building with MinGW is there as well, but at this time is not officially supported and may or may not work.'*

Comment: @john, so, is there just no suitable solution for this? I saw a lot of people built POCO with MinGW-w64. Maybe there is some special flag for cmake --build command?

Comment: Probably found solution. I will try to set up MinGW-w64 posix-seh version. Maybe SEH system will not complain to code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I tried some different variations of MinGW-w64 compiler, but it didn't work. I decided to download MSVC compiler with Microsoft Build Tools and it did pretty well, all libraries compiled